# Azure Data Movement Library - Blob download gets stuck

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In our prod environment, We are downloading blobs and Sometimes I see a behaviour that a file is downloaded about 60% and then nothing happens. It does not errors out nor returns. With this happening the download is stuck indefinitely. The handle to the file where it is written is not released. I am assuming that the task that is create in `StartSchedule()` method in `TransferScheduler` class is running indefinitely. The dumps does not reveal anything. Is there a way to figure what might be the issue ?
I am using version `0.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

I created an C# console project, but I can't repro the issue that you mentioned,  even I used the 4G size file for test. I test with [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement) SDK version 0.5.0 and  0.6.0. The following is the code I used for test.

```
   string storageConnectionString = "connection string";
   CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
   CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
   CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container name");
   blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
   string destPath = "file path";
   CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob name");
   TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
   // Setup the transfer context and track the download progress
   SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext
   {
        ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes download: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
        })
    };
    // download thee blob
    var task = TransferManager.DownloadAsync(
    sourceBlob, destPath, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
    task.Wait();
```

[image]